# Azure - Create Function App - At least one resource deployment operation failed

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I get this error message while deploying on Azure. Any ideas what this could be?

Step 1. Create a function app.

Step 2. Unable to progress (from the Create Function App) in Azure. I get -

Deployment to resource group 'FunctionApp' failed.
Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.

Step 3. I've checked various places. https://aka.ms/arm-debug - this error message is not listed.

How do I fix this? I've not started - I've created a Function App and it's not creating the function app...

Comment: Can you share your ARM template to check possible problems?

Comment: I've contacted Microsoft-support for this. It seems to be a problem with accounts created in the old portal, then upgraded to the new portal.azure.com... I'll update this post when they reply.

Comment: @buttercup You don't have `Owner` role, I add it to an answer. Hope it help more people who meet same issue.

Comment: it's fixed now. They (Microsoft Support) repaired this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manage Azure resource, you need have your subscription `Owner` role. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is).

You could check your user role on Portal.

[image]

Comment: Is "Account Admin" good enough?